# CComSafeArray: Are Indices Really Reversed for MultiDimSetAt and MultiDimGetAt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, visual-c++, atl

In the [MSDN documentation for CComSafeArray::MultiDimSetAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wbystyc.aspx), alIndex is documented as follows:

> Pointer to a vector of indexes for each dimension in the array. **The rightmost (least significant) dimension is alIndex[0].**

In the [documentation for CComSafeArray::MultiDimGetAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e91t4kz.aspx), alIndex is documented differently:

> Pointer to a vector of indexes for each dimension in the array. **The leftmost (most significant) dimension is alIndex[0].**

This made me think that, to get to the same element, one would need to reverse the order of the indices in a multidimensional array. However, I have not found this to be the case in practice.

Am I misusing this interface and getting lucky, misunderstanding the documentation, or is this possibly an error in the docs?

Comment: Most likely that's the way it works. I had to automate excel in a c++ app last year and had to reverse the order of the params in the method call.

Comment: ChadNC, order of parameters in Dispatch's Invoke is not what this question refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be docs error - I'd suggest you to refer to SafeArrayGetElement/SafeArrayPutElement documentation as it seems to be more accurate.

To set and get the same element you should use the same array of indices (without reversing).

By the way, nice catch!